# Bluring Part of an Image in Android

Tags: android, image-processing

is there any way to blur only part of an image in android?

searched a lot but dint find any help.

most of the examples use gaussian blur which blurs full imageview.

i want to allow user to dynamically draw rectangle on imageview & on action up
area within rectangle should be blured.

any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluring images on the fly is not an easy task, ask Roman Nurik (The one behind Muzei app)
He gave useful tips on [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/2sTQ1X2Cb2Z) but it's for animated images, from focus to blur.

In your case, I would say that you need to (roughly):

1. Get the bounds of the drawn rectangle
2. Get the image part that corresponds to the previous bounds
3. Blur on the fly the previous image part
4. Draw, into the same canvas, the blurred image part on top of the original image
5. Set up a onDrag Listener to move the drawn rectangle and do again step 1

**EDIT**: After re-thinking about it, computing and draw a blurred area each time the drawn rectangle move it too heavy, it won't work. The solution is probably this:

1. Blur the entire image and keep it into memory
2. Get the bounds of the drawn rectangle
3. **Get the part of the blurred image that corresponds to the previous bounds**
4. Draw, into the same canvas, the blurred image part on top of the original image
5. Set up a onDrag Listener to move the drawn rectangle to do again step 2-3-4

Comment: Indeed. I updated my answer, I think I found a better way to do it :)

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can please share any example.

Comment: This is how I would have done this. Unfortunately, I don't have any example.

Answer (score 1):

put the image view in a relative layout.
you detect the touch events of the user. 
for each rectangle that he is drawing, you add an image view of it is size superposed to the initial one (I mean in the same relative layout) and of course with your blur effect.
you will see your image view blured part by part ...

Answer (score 0):

put another layout on the half part of the image and set a translucent type background to the layout.

Comment: ok so you can use Drawable's setAlpha() method. It takes an int from 0 to 255, 0 being fully transparent, and 255 being fully opaque.

Comment: before setting the alpha apply a background color to the drawable

Comment: your application is crashing. because of the library. do you want the application to work on a single device or multiple devices??

Comment: use this library which I have put in

Comment: looks like you dont know what is the meaning of blur!

Comment: Looks like you have not seen the code. If you would have gone through it. You would have set the paint properties according to your needs by now.

Comment: for blur you dont need to change paint etc. i was suppose to implement blur algorithm for specific part.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have drawn your rectangle set `alpha = 0.5` or as per your need so that your dynamic view that you have drawn will look blurred.

Answer (score 0):

This is code for blur:
http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.in/2013/07/gaussian-blur-imagebitmap-in-imageview.html

In this code `computeConvolution3x3` method is used for computing the blur.For computing blur it convert the bitmap in to pixel array then it apply on those pixel. So you have to just do is get pixels array of that part of the image that you want blur.

Comment: Its working on my system.By the way try this link [gaussian blur](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-gaussian-blur/) or search for `gaussian blur in android` You would get enough result

Comment: i already tried that it blurs full image. i want only specific part

Comment: yaah i know it it blurs full image.So i have mentioned that u have to change in computeConvlutaion3x3 method